# Using stored procedure as a source of external dictionary

Tags: sql-server, clickhouse

Due to security policy I need to use a stored procedure (MS SQL Server) as a source  of ClickHouse external dictionary via ODBC.

According to documentation for ClickHouse it is possible to use only a table (or view). Although ODBC allows to call stored procedures.

```
<odbc>
    <db>DatabaseName</db>
    <table>TableName</table>
    <connection_string>DSN=some_parameters</connection_string>
    <invalidate_query>SQL_QUERY</invalidate_query>
</odbc>
```

When I tried "{CALL my_procedure_name}" in table I got this error.

> Poco::Exception. Code: 1000, e.code() = 0, e.displayText() = ODBC
>   handle exception: Failed to get number of columns: Connection:NetConn:
>   000000001760E400\nServer:OMEGA_DSN\n===========================\nODBC
>   Diagnostic record #1:\n===========================\nSQLSTATE =
>   42S02\nNative Error Code = 208\n[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL
>   Server][SQL Server]54>?CAB8<>5 81J5:B0 "{CALL
>   my_procedure_name}".\n\n===========================\nODBC Diagnostic
>   record

Can anybody sujest some solution or workaround?

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely due to the incompatibility of the ODBC driver. You may try testing it via https://www.mankier.com/1/isql

As for a workaround, I would start from wrapping the stored procedure in a view.

Comment: It's not possible to execute stored procedure from a view, at list is ms sql server.